# Prisma - Como converter número inteiro em binário?

Tags: prisma

Preciso de uma função na linguagem Prisma que converta um número inteiro para a sua forma em binário. Por exemplo, para converter `255` para `11111111`.

tenho que criar uma fórmula tal qual http://www.raymundodeoliveira.eng.br/binario.html

```
tab = {}                           // declarando uma tabela vazia
funcao bits(n)                     // "n" é o número inteiro
    enquanto verdadeiro inicio     // laço para preencher a tabela
    n = n / 2                      // divido n por 2 até chegar a 0
    resto = "resto de n por 2"     // tenho que pegar o resto da divisão
    tabela.insira(tab,1,resto)     // alimentando a tabela
    fim                            // fim do laço
    retorne tab                    // retorna a tabela com os binários
fim

imprima(bits(255))                 //--------- saída >> 11111111
```

Comment: Para quem não sabe o que é prisma: http://linguagemprisma.br4.biz

Comment: Esse comentário não foi para você. Foi para outras pessoas que vierem ver a sua pergunta e não entenderem do que se trata.

Comment: Bem, editei a pergunta e votei para reabrir. Se você colocar nela o código que você já tentou fazer, ajuda a convencer outros usuários a reabri-la.

Comment: O que eu perguntei foi como converter inteiro em binário e não em hexadecimal. Agora se a função fizer algo a mais, ponto pra ela.

Comment: Você quer retornar uma tabela? Retornar uma string com zeros e uns não seria melhor?

Comment: eu coloquei uma tabela porque me veio na cabeça, mas pode ser uma cadeia também, pra mim tanto faz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, é melhor você evitar variáveis globais e preferir usar variáveis locais. Em quase nenhuma linguagem usar variável global é boa prática de programação e é muito fácil fazer-se um código bem amarrado, confuso, bugado e difícil de se mexer ao usar-se variáveis globais. Portanto, evite-as sempre.

Segundo, acho que retornar como string é melhor. Use `..` para concatenar strings.

Terceiro, o operador de resto da divisão é o `%`.

Quarto, use a função `mat.corte` para remover as frações. O motivo é que você quer que a divisão por dois a cada etapa seja uma divisão inteira.

Quinto, o laço deve rodar até o número se tornar zero.

Sexto, coloquei dois `se` para lidar com o zero e com números negativos.

Eis o código:

```
// "n" é o número inteiro.
funcao bits(n)
    // Lida com o caso especial de n ser zero.
    se n == 0 entao
        retorne "0"
    fim

    // Declara uma string inicialmente vazia.
    local resposta = ""

    // Verifica se é negatiovo para colocar o sinal de menos depois.
    local menos = falso
    se n < 0 entao
        menos = verdadeiro
        n = -n
    fim

    // Laço para preencher a string.
    enquanto n > 0 inicio
        // Pega o resto da divisão.
        local resto = n % 2

        // Isola os demais dígitos do número.
        n = mat.corte(n / 2)

        // Alimenta a string.
        resposta = resto .. resposta
    fim

    // Coloca o sinal de menos de volta, se necessário.
    se menos entao
        resposta = "-" .. resposta
    fim

    // Retorna a string com os binários.
    retorne resposta
fim

imprima(bits(255))
imprima(bits(-5))
imprima(bits(5))
imprima(bits(48973568))
imprima(bits(0))
imprima(bits(1))
imprima(bits(-1))
imprima(bits(2))
```

Observe essas instruções `imprima` no final. Elas estão ali para testar o programa. Eis a saída produzida:

```
11111111
-101
101
10111010110100011100000000
0
1
-1
10
```

Observe que esse números binários produzidos são os esperados, então é posssível crer-se que a minha implementação está correta.

Ah, e esta é a primeira vez que tive contato com essa linguagem. Antes de ver a sua pergunta, nem sabia que existia.